# How to use one REST API RESPONSE property, and use it in another REST API header property

Tags: rest, api, soapui, response-headers, property-transfer

I would like to know how to property transfer from one REST API to another REST API?

I worked on the property transfer with the JSON format, but I need to know how to transfer the one REST API response property and use it in the header?

Comment: It is a bit difficult to answer this question without further leads. Are you using only SOAPUI alone or are you using any rest client that you wrote in a language as well? When you say "I worked on property transfer with JSON format", were you using any code for that?

Comment: Hello Kavitha! I tried to get the REST API response as the input parameter in another REST API like to use the response like to use in a header values in another REST API. And I don't need to use any API as well. I hope you got it and more more thing I am doing this POC in Soap UI PRO in ReadyAPI 2.8.2

Comment: It is still not clear to me. I've seen in implementations where the server sends a location header for a new POST request and the client takes the URL from the location header and use it for the subsequent GET request. I did not understand the part where you do not use any kind of API - can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

let me explain this using the below scenario:

1. Admin get the User object by API
2. Save apiKey from the user object
3. Call the action on user behalf(By set `Authorization Header` to `Basic` with the user apiKey)

To accomplish these steps in soapUI You have to:

1. Define `apiKey` in `Custom Properties` in `TestCase`
2. Call resource that returns a User object
3. Save `apiKey` property to `TestCase.apiKey` via property transfer or `Groovy`   Step
4. Reuse `TestCase.apiKey` in your nest `REST Request` step by expanding it via `Basic ${=(testCase.getPropertyValue("apiKey")+":").bytes.encodeBase64()}`

[image]

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for your help snieguu but I am not using the API. So how can I do that without the API but using any other property transfer or any other one?